# invalid literal for int() with base 10: On form data from ajax

Tags: python, ajax, flask

```
@server.route('/bet', methods=['GET','POST'])
def bet():
with sqlite3.connect("steamid.db") as con:
    if g.user:
        steamdata = get_steam_userinfo(g.user.steam_id)
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT coins FROM user WHERE steam_id=?", (steamdata['steamid'],))
        user_coins = c.fetchall()
        user_coins = user_coins[0][0]
        steam_id = steamdata['steamid']
        steam_nick = steamdata['personaname']
        authlink = '''
            <a href="/logout">logout</a>
            '''
        coins = int(request.form.get('betting_coins', ''))
        print(coins)
```

I get the error (invalid literal for int() with base 10:). The thing is when I print coins in the console it says 200 which should be a valid integer and also shows that the data came through in the request, so coins should not be a Nonetype.

How I posted to data:

```
function bet() {
var betting_coins = document.getElementById('bet_coins').value;
        alert(betting_coins);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/bet",
            type: "POST",
            data: {betting_coins: betting_coins}
        });

        //location.href = "/bet";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
coins = int(request.form.get('betting_coins', ''))
```

which defaults to `''`, which isn't a valid literal for `int()`. Try changing it to 0 or something. Or else, you could add a `try/catch`.